# Wrong Data Type when Looping an Array Function in VBA for Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I have a function in VBA for Excel that returns a 2 dimensional array.
In addition I have another function that takes two members of that array and adds them together.
Lastly, I have a third function that loops on the second function's result until a certain value is reached.

The first two functions work fine. I can index the array in a worksheet and I can make a get good results in a cell for the second function.
The third function also works but only if I comment out the looping portion.  When I enable the `do loop` in the third function I receive "A value used in the formula is the wrong data type" error in the cell.

I tried solving the problem by making everything a double (as shown in the code).

I've also commented out the `Do While` and `Loop` lines and verified that the code runs as long as it's not looping.

This is function 1:

```vb
Function makeArray1(aaa As Double, bbb As Double, ccc As Double) As Double()
    Dim workArray() As Double

    ReDim workArray(1 To 4, 1 To 3)
    workArray(1, 1) = aaa
    workArray(1, 2) = bbb
    workArray(1, 3) = ccc
    workArray(2, 1) = aaa + 1
    workArray(2, 2) = bbb + 1
    workArray(2, 3) = ccc + 1
    workArray(3, 1) = aaa + bbb
    workArray(3, 2) = bbb + ccc
    workArray(3, 3) = ccc + aaa
    workArray(4, 1) = 1
    workArray(4, 2) = 2
    workArray(4, 3) = 3

    makeArray1 = workArray()
End Function
```

This is function 2:

```vb
Function findValue1(aaa As Double, bbb As Double, ccc As Double) As Double
    Dim Value As Double
    Dim result() As Double

    result = makeArray1(aaa, bbb, ccc)
    Value = result(1, 3) + result(4, 3)

    findValue1 = Value
End Function
```

This is function 3:

```vb
Function valueLoop(aaa As Double, bbb As Double) As Double
    Dim seed As Double
    Dim importantValue As Double

    seed = 1#

    Do While seed < 100#
     importantValue = findValue1(aaa, bbb, seed)
     seed = seed + 1#
    Loop

    valueLoop = importantValue
End Function
```

I am expecting the loop to run until `seed = 100`. Then the result of the `valueLoop` or `importantValue` should be 102.

The error message I get is a `#VALUE!` in the cell with the description: "A value used in the formula is the wrong data type".

Comment: I may have solved my problem.  Note my actual code is much more complecated but, it turns out I get this error if I feed too many or too few cells into function 3.  It doesn't totally explain my code's behavior as it works when not looping, but it has given me a clue that it may have to do with a "datatype" of a number I'm feeding into the functions.

I'll have to wait until I'm back at work to check this out.

Comment: I forgot to include my cells in excel used to test the code:

a2 = 10
b2 = 20
c2 = 30

And I make these aaa, bbb, & ccc, respectively.  It looks something like this:

aaa bbb ccc  findValue1 Function valueLoop
10 20 30  33                                 #VALUE!

Comment: For user-defined functions, `#VALUE!` in the cell means that an error happened in the function. Instead of guessing what it was, call the function directly from a macro with the same parameters it is called with from the sheet, and observe the error.

Comment: Specifically for this code and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905869/wrong-data-type-when-looping-an-array-function-in-vba-for-excel#comment100356521_56905869) set of data, calling `valueLoop` from a cell gives `102`.